# Doctrine 2.3 Criteria. Accessing a related Object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, criteria

I am trying to set up a Criteria according to [the Doctrine Docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

Unfortunately they don't tell you how to access attributes of an related Object. Let me give you an example.

I have an ArrayCollection of Products. Every Product has a Category. I want to filter the ArrayCollection for a Category Name. Now I am trying to set up a Criteria as follows:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
  ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("category.name", "SomeCategoryName"));
```

Now I get the following Exception:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unrecognized field: category.name")
```

How can I access a related Object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I looked into the source code `Criteria::expr()->eq("name", --- second value ---)`. Second value expects an instance of `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr\Value`. So it's not possible to put another `Expr` or `criteria` in there. Only the `Expr` `And` and `Or` take another `Expr`.
I'm pretty sure you are suppose to solve this with other functions like `filter()` or get an iterator with `getIterator()`. This is how it can be done with the `filter()` method.

```
$filteredProducts = 
    $products->filter(function($key, $element) use ($categoryName) {
        return $element->getCategory()->getName() === categoryName;
    });
```

If you can an `Iterator` for each next relation you can nest foreach loops and filter inside those.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test your `Ctriteria` on monday. Right now I don't have access to my workstation. I will let you know if it works. However filter is a bad idea in my opinion, because all Categories will be eager loaded and then processed locally on the disk (What will never be as perfomant than doing it on a DB).

Comment: You are misinformed. Criteria can be used in a query (data to be fetched) as well as on an ArrayCollection (already fetched data). If you didn't make fetch-joins the relation will be eager loaded whether you use criteria or filter(). You are right that the DB gives you most performance so it's best to use fetch join in combination with WHERE. Though that was not what your question was about.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to annotate your entities, so that they are lazy loaded? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytoone. Wouldn't that load the `ArrayCollection` lazy? Or wouldn't that work because that's the inverse Annotation?

Comment: They are lazy loaded by default if you don't specify the annotation for it. However when you are using criteria (with the matching() method) on a non-retreived ArrayCollection it will start to lazy load just as well as it would with filter(). The owning/inverse possibility is unrelated to this.

Comment: ```matching``` method with ```Criteria``` loads only those records that satisfy that criteria. ```filter``` method forces full collection load.

Comment: Yet super useful

Answer (score 4):

That probably belongs in a repository method, rather than a filter method. If you're wanting to get a pre-filtered list of Products in a collection on a parent object (like an Order or something), you can filter the child collection in the query builder. However, you have to deal with the possibly confusing side-effect of not having fully hydrated objects.

This should give you a list of `Order` objects, which only having `Product` children matching a category name.

```
class OrderRepository extends EntityRepository {
  public function findOrderWithProductCategory($category)
  {
    $builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
      ->select('o, p')
      ->leftJoin('o.products', 'p')
      ->join('p.category', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.name = :category')
      ->setParameter('category', $category);
  }
}
```

---

If you don't know what kind of categories you're interested until later, then you're probably better using @Flip's solution anyway, and pre-hydrating all the categories. Using [partial hydration](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax) and standard `ArrayCollection::filter()` closures, performs pretty well in most cases.

That said, it would be quite nice as a feature. I suspect the Doctrine guys would be reluctant because the current `Criteria` implementation is very light-weight and they probably want to keep it that way.

Comment: indeed, this [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/pull/27) is already opened: