# Symfony2 Criteria filtering OneToMany

Tags: symfony, filter, one-to-many, criteria

I have an Entity called 'User', which has a OnetoMany relation in a field called 'books'.

I also have an Entity called 'Book' which has many attributes, like, 'title' or 'date'.

There ir another entity called 'Date', which attributes are: 'day', 'month' and 'year'.

I want to filter the books that the user has which are from year 2009.

I am tring to do it like this, using Criteria, but I recieve an error because field date.year does not exist:

```
$books = $user->getBooks(); 

$criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("date.year", "2009"));

$books_2009 = $books->matching($criteria);
```

Any idea of how can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151567/doctrine-2-3-criteria-accessing-a-related-object]

Comment: it is not clear for me in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("year", "2009"));
```

This should work. Please let me know.

Comment: I have edited my question, because I did not explain everything well. Please, take a look at it again. I need to filter by the year, which is inside Date entity.