# symfony2 filtering on related entities with entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have searched google for hours now and I can't seem to find the answer i'm looking for.  In Symfony2, I am attempting to use the Criteria::create() and filter on a season and its not working.  Here's the full explanation:

I have 4 Entitys: User, UserPolicy, Role and Season.  UserPolicy implements the RoleInterface and User implements the UserInterface.

User.php

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserPolicy", mappedBy="User", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $Polocies;

}
```

UserPolicy.php

```
class UserPolicy Implements RoleInterface
{
    /**
     * @Id()
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="Polocies")
     * @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $User;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
     * @JoinColumn(name="roleid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $Role;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Season")
     * @JoinColumn(name="seasonid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $Season;
}
```

Role.php

```
class Role{

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="role", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $Role;

    /**
     * @Column(name="label", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $Label;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $Parent;
}
```

Note the $Season variable on the UserPolicy.

Each year there will be a new season, and users will get a new set of policies, keeping the previous seasons policies.

In User.php, I need to call getRoles() which works and i can get the UserPolicies which have the roles attached to them and that works too.

The problem is introduced when i need to filter on the Seasons.  I found the Criteria class:

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("Season", "1"));
```

But because Season is an object, I'm getting the error

```
Cannot match on AppBundle\Entity\UserPolicy::Season with a non-object value. Matching objects by id is not compatible with matching on an in-memory collection, which compares objects by reference.
```

How do I fetch the Season Object if i'm not supposed to be able to load other data in the User Entity?  I don't know how to pass the Season Object.  I even created a service to access the season object, but I can't access the get() function inside the Entity.  HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151567/doctrine-2-3-criteria-accessing-a-related-object) which describes a similar issue to yours.
It's not possible to use the criteria in the way you described.

So there are three solutions:

1. Fetch the entire collection and then filter it by season like in [the question I mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151567/doctrine-2-3-criteria-accessing-a-related-object).
2. Create a repository method to fetch user policies by season id.
3. First fetch the season, and then use it in the default `findBy()` method of the entity repository.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 are helpful but The issue is on the getRoles which is required for the user interface. I can't use a repository method within the entity, and o can't fetch another entity within a entity.

Comment: In that case I think the simplest solution would be to go with option one and filter the policies in `getRoles()` method. Unless you're going to have god knows how many of these policies, it won't be a problem performance wise.

Comment: I like option one and it makes a lot of sence. However when implementing it, I realize that the if of 1 was hard coded. Is there a way to access a global variable that I could put the season in since its its own entity?

Comment: Well, you could create a separate method which takes the season in as parameter, and the `getRoles()` method would simply invoke that method with a parameter. This gives you some flexibility but still doesn't solve your issue. Assuming you will always want `getRoles()` to return the policies for the current season, you might want to mark the policies from the previous one as expired when a season comes to an end, and use that to filter them out.

Comment: I was unsuccessful in applying these solutions.  Here's why:

1. i can't filter this way because the season may change dynamically when the user attempts to view previous seasons, and the 'current season' object is stored in a service.  I don't have access to the service to be able to check what season we're in.

2. I can not access the repository in the entity class, therefore creating a reposiiory method won't work.

3. Again, I don't have access to the entity manager inside the entity, so I can't fetch the seasons.

Remember this is inside the getRoles() function called bu the system.

Comment: Do you need to be able to show these policies somewhere or are they just internal ? Now that I think of it... You might want `getRoles()` to return all policies, and check/filter them in the voters, controller or views where you would have access to the current season. You might want to create a helper  service for that if you need that a lot.